# Facebook doesn't get the information from my site

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Hello I set all the tags that facebook ask for, but still where I go to my account in facebook and I type the URL of this website brings just the text but not the logo, the actual tag of the text are these:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="title of site"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="site name"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Text"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/templates/tem-et/images/logo.png"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="es_ES" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
```

I change the information because this url cannot be publish, so far is not ready, all the URL from the tags and the path to 'image' is correct but Facebook doesn't show the logo of the website. What should I change?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook caches details about your site when a link to it is shared. You can clear the cache for your URL here:

- http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

For more information about Facebook's caching see here:

- http://umairj.com/146/how-to-clear-facebook-shares-cache/

Comment: I did it, but still the same doesn't show me the logo of the site, it can be cause it is .png? thanks

Comment: I tried accessing your image:  http://www.example.com/templates/tem-et/images/logo.png  and nothing came up.  So check your URL and make sure it is properly exposed to the internet.  It may be accessible behind your firewall while you're testing it.  Have some other people not on your network try the url too.   Be sure to check your page here too: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: `example.com` is certainly *not* going to work. Presumably he's obfuscated things in that example he posted.

Comment: example.com is not my domain, but as we didn't realease the website yet I cannot post the original link, I check all the links to the image, url, etc and all the url are correct, also if I go to developers.facebook.com/tools/debug no error come up, and it show the logo in the image section, but not when I write the url in facebook. Some other thing to check? Thanks